# Extending a controller doesn't appear to work

Tags: overrides, controllers

I'm trying to externd a controller. The customer controller to be exact. I found a example on [Inchoo](http://inchoo.net/dev-talk/how-to-extend-magento-core-controller/) But I can't get it to work.

I tried turning off all othermodules. I've checked everything multipletimes. Nothing seems to work.
We run Magento 1.9.0.1

**app/code/local/MyModule/Custompasswordforget/controllers/AccountController.php**

```
<?php
require_once(Mage::getModuleDir('controllers','Mage_Customer').DS.'AccountController.php')
//die('hit this file');  // doesn't work
class MyModule_Custompasswordforget_AccountController extends Mage_Customer_AccountController {
  public function forgotPasswordAction()
  {
    //die('hit this method');  // doesn't work

    parent::forgotPasswordAction();
  }
}
```

**app/code/local/MyModule/Custompasswordforget/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <MyModule_Custompasswordforget>
      <version>0.9.0</version>
    </MyModule_Custompasswordforget>
  </modules>
  <frontend>
    <routers>
      <customer>
        <args>
          <modules>
            <MyModule_Custompasswordforget before="Mage_Customer_AccountController">
              MyModule_Custompasswordforget
            </MyModule_Custompasswordforget>
          </modules>
        </args>
      </customer>
    </routers>
  </frontend>
</config>
```

**app/etc/modules/MyModule_Custompasswordforget.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <MyModule_Custompasswordforget>
      <version>0.9.0</version>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
    </MyModule_Custompasswordforget>
  </modules>
</config>
```

I'm afraid for a small oversight but I just can't find it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If that really is your xml then try it with the `<MyModule_Custompasswordforget before="Mage_Customer_AccountController">MyModule_Custompasswordforget</MyModule_Custompasswordforget>` on a single line as newlines can mess the xml up

Comment: Nice words David :-) Linebreaks in Magento config.xml files in text-entities are ALWAYS a problem :-)

Comment: this line space issue so irritate me.... :)

Comment: That can really be the problem? :S I'll ty it tomorrow.

Comment: I hate Magento. Is it really that hard to `trim()` something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make your routers section from config.xml look like this:

```
<routers>
  <customer>
    <args>
      <modules>
        <MyModule_Custompasswordforget before="Mage_Customer">MyModule_Custompasswordforget</MyModule_Custompasswordforget>
      </modules>
    </args>
  </customer>
</routers>
```

remove the spaces inside the tags because magento does not trim the values.
Your module router should be loaded before the `Magento_Customer` module not `Magento_Customer_AccountController.`